# Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink) - Can I have more than one of these subs in a worksheet object?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using Excel from MSFT 365.  I am an excel expert but a VBA novice.

I created the following code within a worksheet object which essentially moves the workbook to a designated page and filters based on the value in the cell that was clicked initially.

```
Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 3 To 5000
    
        If Target.Range.Address = "$B$" & i Then
        Worksheets("Jobs").Range("A2").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Worksheets("Orders").Range("B" & i)
        End If
      
    Next i

End Sub
```

My question is the following. Can I add another similar sub within this same worksheet object using the same action?  If I use the same action, I get an ambiguous name error because both subs are named the same (and I don't think I can change the name of the sub).

Or, do I have to incorporate all actions into this single Worksheet_FollowHyperlink sub?

Comment: You can only have one `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` event handler in a worksheet. But it can call other subroutines.

Comment: Thanks - I was afraid that that might be the answer.

Comment: You are right....maybe I should have said "I thought that might be the case...." :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Application.Intersect` here - no need to loop

```vb
Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Dim rng As Range
    
    'Is Target in B3:B5000 ?
    'in a worksheet code module `Me` refers to the sheet itself
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target.Range, Me.Range("B3:B5000"))
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then 'in range?
        Worksheets("Jobs").Range("A2").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=rng.Value
    End If

    'Add other case(s) here....

End Sub
```